# Location's Distance/Proximity exposed filter without Node Location Submodule but with Location CCK Submodule instead

Tags: location, views

I would like to stay a little bit more flexible and use Location CCK fields (from Location CCK Submodule) instead of Node Locations (from Node Locations submodule) on my nodes. However, in my view of nodes the "distance/proximity" exposed filter (distance from a user-entered zip code) only works when my nodes have a location attached to them via Node Locations Submodule. If I disable Node Locations Submodule and attach a location to my nodes via a Location CCK field, the "distance/proximity" exposed filter never returns any results.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Best,
deinqwertz

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and "solved" with a little workaround:

I use both node and cck location. The one is hidden from the user, he only sees one, and if it is changed then I copy it into the other one.

That way I have both a cck field for flexibility's sake AND the node location for the views. :)